# jQuery fixed sliding panel height

Tags: jquery, sticky-footer

So I have a header at 145px in height and a sticky footer set to 200px in height.

I have hidden under the footer a sliding content panel that slides up when a button above the footer is activated. This panel is 330px in height and is absolutely positioned to the footer.

Making an overall minimum screen real estate of 675px.

What I'm wondering is, if a user was for instance to be using a small notebook laptop for example how can I get the height of the screen, then if the height is smaller than say 700px push the sliding panel down.

I think what I'd need to do is determine by how much the height is under 700px then whatever it is add this to push the panel down, so if the screen height was 650px, push the div down by 50px. I could use the footer as a div to push down or maybe use this calculation to increase the negative margin being used on the push/body to force the footer down.

Any thoughts welcome.

Thanks
Geoff

Answer (score 0):

take a look to these links :

[CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and 
[JS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.matchMedia)

Comment: Hi akio, great articles and I already work allot with CSS Media Queries as these are responsive projects but what I need to do is calculate the difference and use this to add to an element. If I knew how much padding or margin I wanted I could use your suggestions but I don't. I don't want to write lots of: if screen height is less than x add 10px, if it's less than y add 30px and so on.

Comment: ok maybe something like this :
    `var clienHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    if(clientHeight < x){
        add 10px
    }else if(clientHeight < y){
        add 30px
    }`

Comment: Hi akio, that's what I'd like to avoid, sorry. Here is a simple explenation of the calculation I want to make.

If screen height is less than 700px in height, get the amount it is less by and add this to another div, so for example:

screen height calculation is found to be 650px high, add 50px to #div

.get screen height
.is it lower than 700px
.if so by how much
.add this to a div

Comment: I did a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EFHvb). It's something like that you're looking for ?

Comment: Hi akio, sorry but no it's not.

Comment: would like help you but it'll be more easy with a drawing or jsfiddle of what you expect or code what you have